# Polynomial Ring: Root vs. Remainder

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, spectral-theory, banach-algebras

**Framework:**

Consider a unital ring: $e\in R$
and a given polynomial: $p\in R[X]$
*(Note that I do not require the ring to be an integral domain.)*

**Problem:**

If it has a root then it factorizes: $p(\lambda)=0 \Rightarrow p=(X-\lambda)q$

**Application:**

Consider a unital algebra: $\mathcal{A}$
over the complex numbers: $R=\mathbb{C}$
For a given element: $A\in\mathcal{A}$
and investigate its spectrum: $\sigma(A)$

Then the spectral theorem holds: $\sigma(p(A))=p(\sigma(A))$

**Discussion:**

Intermediate within the proof the assertion arises that *at least* one factor cannot be invertible:
$$\mu\in\sigma(p(A))\Rightarrow \lambda_{i_0}\in\sigma(A)\qquad\text{ with }\mu-p(A)\propto(\lambda_1-A)\cdots(\lambda_{I}-A)$$
So one might wonder wether *all* roots necessarily belong to the spectrum:
$$\mu\in\sigma(p(A))\Rightarrow\lambda_1,\ldots\lambda_I\in\sigma(A)$$
Moreover what happens if the field is not algebraically closed as in the reals: $R=\mathbb{R}$
Can it happen in this case that the inclusion becomes proper: $\sigma(p(A))\supsetneq p\sigma(A))$

Comment: Please describe the entire problem so we can see the context.

Comment: @freeze_S It's obvious you have a question in mind, but it won't be obvious to all readers what you're asking. To make the post complete, please clearly mention the objective of your question in the body of the post.

Comment: I already got it by a colleague but will add it for completeness ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

By polynomial division it has a representation as:
$$p=(X-\lambda)q+r\qquad{deg}(r)<1$$
Evaluation yields:
$$0=p(\lambda)=(\lambda-\lambda)q(\lambda)+r(\lambda)=0+c_0\qquad r=c_0X^0$$
That is: $r=0$

Concluding: $p=(X-\lambda)q$

Comment: Can we do polynomial long division in an arbitrary unital ring?

Comment: Yes indeed we can! I did just prove it really carefully: The leading coefficient of the the divisor must be a unit. Moreover the order of divisor and quotient effects the result; however, polynomial long division will work in both cases.